# Does a path exist going through each color only once?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, decision-problem, network-flow

I have a directed, colored graph (each node has a color), and I want to find if a path from node A to node B exists such that the path goes through each color at MOST once.

I think this problem can be formulated using network flow. Somehow a penalty can be placed on nodes of the same color that makes the flow 0 or infinity if a node is repeated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem looks really similar to  an exercise from the 'Algorithm Design' book by Kleinberg & Tardos. The exercise in question is 8.12  and the goal is to prove NP Completeness.  So try thinking about a possible reduction.

Comment: Thats interesting. I'm pretty sure the problem is in P, but I'll look into that.

Comment: @jjohn Note how different the question "I'd like to have an algorithm for X" is from "What is the complexity of X". In particular, proving NP-hardness does not answer the first one.

Comment: It's not for HW... However, I do think that the problem is NOT NP-Hard or NP-Complete.

Comment: @PK5144 So are you interested in just a hardness proof, or do you also want some algorithm for solving the problem? (A non-polynomial one, that is).

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/148991/755

Answer (score 3):

I understand from your question that you are asking for a polynomial-time algorithm for solving the problem. It is unlikely there is one for the problem.

Taking the hint of @jjohn, this is exactly the same problem as in the Kleinberg-Tardos book, Exercise 8.12. They call the problem *evasive path*. Here, color classes represent different zones, and you must get from $s$ to $t$ visiting each zone at most once.

There are at least two straightforward reductions. The other one is from directed Hamiltonian path, and the other one from set partitioning, i.e. [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover). If you still care about solving the problem, you can do it in $O^*(2^k)$-time, where $k$ is the number of colors.

Comment: What is the reduction from directed hamiltonian path to evasive path?

Comment: Give each vertex its own color?

Answer (score 0):

This is NPC and we can reduce a $k$-SAT problem (usually $3$-SAT) to this.

Firstly given a $3$-SAT problem, we can construct a full-connected directed graph: a source node $s$, a sink node $t$ and some layers. Each layer comes from a clause in the SAT problem and have $3$ (or $k$) nodes.

Then we let each pair of nodes form a zone/color if they are oppositie, i.e., $x$ and $\bar{x}$. So it's easy to see that we can find such a path from $s$ to $t$, if and only if there is a solution for the SAT problem.